# Find desired attributes of a file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

If i am looking for certain attributes on a file, e.g. "r-x" for user, a regular expression like '^-r.x' will do the job. But, what if i have to show files that user and others have the same rights for "write" attribute? Ok, what i though was to pass to awk the result of stat command:

```
stat --format="%a %n" filename (permissions in octal + name)
```

an then use the script:

```
others=$1 % 10;
group = ($1 % 100 - others)/10;
owner = int($1 / 100);
```

to get the permissions for each one and then

```
switch (owner) {

case 7:
case 6:
case 3:
case 2:

    if (other!=1 || other !=4 || other!=5)

        print $2;

case 1:
case 4:
case 5:
```

I guess there must be a way more simplest way, though...

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather go for `find`:

```
find -type f -perm -u+w,o+w -o \( ! -perm -u+w -a ! -perm -o+w \)
```

Will find files `b` and `c` from:

```
$ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 0 Dez 19 16:13 a
-r--r--r-- 1 john john 0 Dez 19 16:13 b
-rw-r--rw- 1 john john 0 Dez 19 16:13 c
```

Be careful with the logics though: the seemingly simpler

```
\( ! -perm -u+w,o+w \)
```

for matching files without write permissions for user and others would match both match `a` AND `b`.